# how to sort numbers alphabetically?

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to write a program that sorts numbers alphabetically in C.

Example Input:

> 2 35 6 8 4

Example Output:

> 8 4 6 35 2

Digits should be sorted corresponding to the words representing them, like:

> 1-one
>
> 2-two
>
> 3-three
>
> 4-four
>
> 5-five
>
> 6-six
>
> 7-seven
>
> 8-eight
>
> 9-nine

I'm able to sort single digits using `switch` cases. What is the best way to sort two or more digits?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to ask. Do you want the numbers to be sorted as they are written in english? For eg for input: 34 32 should the o/p be 34 32 ("thirty four" < "thirty two")?

Comment: Yes. It should be sorted as it is in english.

Comment: @DeepakRese I edited your formatting a bit. Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

One way, not most efficient would be: (Will give you just hints to solve the problem and not complete solution)

1. Use `sprintf` to convert numbers to string and store in an array of string. If you want to convert numbers to spelling, use [this excellent tutorial](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/). (pops on top of the google search)
2. Sort the string using qsort with below comparision function. Use a `struct` with number tagged with string if you want the number back.

**Comparision function**

```
static int
cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
}
```

3. [Optional] Extract the numbers back from the tag.

Comment: How do I convert 987 to ninehundread eighty seven

Comment: Check the updated answer, I added a link.

Comment: Can't find the link.

Comment: Click over **[This excellent tutorial](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words)**

Answer (score 0):

Any time you need to sort collections of related data by one value or another, you should be thinking `struct`. A structure holding each of the various values, (`int` value, `char *` of integer, and `char *` word for integer), can be sorted on any of them and provide you a way to correlate your values regardless of the sort order.

You basic challenge is to fill an array of struct with each of the values, sort on the `char *` *word for integer*, and then use it as you need. The various conversions are fairly straight forward, (1) convert the `int` to its `char *` equivalent (basically the opposite of `itoa`); and (2) use the lookup table to concatenate your word equivalents based on each digit in (1). (no need to leave a space between the word digits, unless you just feel like it)

Look over the following example. It is just one way to do what you are trying to do. Let me know if you have an questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {MAXC = 32, MAXW = 64};

/* struct holding both integer and number strings */
typedef struct bs {
    int v;
    char buf[MAXC];
    char str[MAXW];
} bs;

const char *numbers[] = { "zero",   /* string lookup */
                          "one",
                          "two",
                          "three",
                          "four",
                          "five",
                          "six",
                          "seven",
                          "eight",
                          "nine" };

char *l2str (long v, char *str, size_t *l);
static int cmpbsp (const void *p1, const void *p2);

int main (void) {

    int array[] = {2, 35, 6, 8, 4};
    int i, n = sizeof array/sizeof *array;
    bs bufstr[n];   /* array of struct */
    size_t len = 0;

    memset (bufstr, 0, n * sizeof *bufstr);     /* initialize to zero */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {                   /* for each in array  */
        bufstr[i].v = array[i];                 /* fill integer val   */
        l2str (array[i], bufstr[i].buf, &len);  /* convert to str     */
        char *p = bufstr[i].buf;
        for (; *p; p++)         /* concatenate number for each digit  */
            strcat (bufstr[i].str, numbers[*p - '0']);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)             /* print original sort order  */
        printf (" bufstr[%d]  v : %2d  buf : %2s  str : %s\n",
                i, bufstr[i].v, bufstr[i].buf, bufstr[i].str);
    putchar ('\n');

    qsort (bufstr, n, sizeof *bufstr, cmpbsp);      /* qsort on str   */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) /* print integers alpha-sorted on numbers */
        printf (" bufstr[%d]  v : %2d  buf : %2s  str : %s\n",
                i, bufstr[i].v, bufstr[i].buf, bufstr[i].str);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

/** convert long to string reversing digits in place.
 *  base 10 conversion of long value 'v' to string 'str'
 *  with string length returned through 'l'. 'd' is a
 *  pointer to the first digit in 'str' used to reverse
 *  the order of the digits in 'str' in place.
 */
char *l2str (long v, char *str, size_t *l)
{
    if (!str) return NULL;

    char *d, *p;
    char tmp;

    /* initialize pointers & length */
    d = p = str;
    *l = 0;

    /* handle negative */
    if (v < 0) {
        *p++ = '-';
        v = -v;
        d++;
    }

    /* convert to char, terminate */
    while (v > 0) {
        *p++ = (v % 10) + '0';
        v /= 10;
    }
    *p = 0;
    *l = (size_t)(p - str);

    /* reverse digits in place */
    while (--p > d) {
        tmp = *p;
        *p-- = *d;
        *d++ = tmp;
    }

    return str;
}

/* simple struct compare based on str */
static int cmpbsp (const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return strcmp (((bs *)p1)->str, ((bs *)p2)->str);
}
```

**Output**

The *original* order and then *alpha-sorted* order (based on `one`, `two`, ...) are shown below.

```
$ ./bin/alphasortintarray
 bufstr[0]  v :  2  buf :  2  str : two
 bufstr[1]  v : 35  buf : 35  str : threefive
 bufstr[2]  v :  6  buf :  6  str : six
 bufstr[3]  v :  8  buf :  8  str : eight
 bufstr[4]  v :  4  buf :  4  str : four

 bufstr[0]  v :  8  buf :  8  str : eight
 bufstr[1]  v :  4  buf :  4  str : four
 bufstr[2]  v :  6  buf :  6  str : six
 bufstr[3]  v : 35  buf : 35  str : threefive
 bufstr[4]  v :  2  buf :  2  str : two
```

*note:* as mentioned in the comment where you are provided a link to convert numbers to words, you can improve the conversion by adding *teens*, and *tens powers* (e.g. `thirteen`, `thirty`, etc..) with just a bit of additional effort.